# Sencha Cmd - How can I change a namespace of existing application

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd5

I have an application on ExtJS 5.0.1 (Sencha Cmd 5.0.2) with a namespace *Fox* (Fox.MainPanel, Fox.ClientsGrid, etc). I need to change name of the application (namespace) to *Wolf* , and it must be Wolf.MainPanel, Wolf.Utils, Wolf.GridPanel in all of the application. 
How I can do it?

Comment: At runtime? Or just renaming all of the code?

Comment: Remove Fox as it is. And use Wolf instead, and use all automatical features of Sencha Cmd in the future.. Manual renaming can broke something.. May be in configs have namespace property and it can be made automatically, with using Sencha Cmd commands

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you could achieve a similar effect by `Wolf = Fox`. This would allow you to access all the objects via the Wolf namespace *as well as* the Fox namespace.

If you need to do it in the code, then search-and-replace is your friend.

Comment: Thanks! May be Sencha Cmd have such feature.. Something like change namespace in sencha.cfg and run 'sencha app refresh'... I am about this